# Notifications from google beacon dashboard are not showing

Tags: beacon, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I bought some beacons, registered them to google dashboard with the app "beacon tools", they are registered as eddystone-UID, everything went fine, added some Notifications to them as attachments, tried with 3 different smartphones, none of them received the notifications.

the URLs used are https, you will see them in the screenshot, I've also tried to create an "eddystone-url" with the app "beacon simulator" and the URLs were working fine.

I know they only work with Bluetooth and internet access, and that I need to be engaged with the phone before they appear.

At first, I was thinking the issue could be related to the beacon (hardware), then I tried to create an ibeacon trough beacon simulator and register it to the same project, also added a URL as an attachment, still was not receiving any notification.

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

[image: Attachments ss]

Comment: I verified the validator works for your URLs: https://beaufortfrancois.github.io/sandbox/physical-web/url-validator/  Perhaps Nearby is not enabled on your phones?

Comment: I don't think that's the case David, as i said, i've tried using the URLs with beacon simulator (it's an app that allows to simulate beacons and you can create an eddystone-URL there), and i've received notifications from there, also, i've tested with 3 smartphones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identified the problem, i'm brazilian, in the "language" section i entered "br"(what usually is used to identify brazil), i didn't pay enough attention, but taking a closer look at the field, it says language (not country), and also says that it should be according to ISO 639-1, in this ISO br means breton, since the smartphones used for the tests are configured for portuguese, we should set "pt", after changing the language the notification worked.

at the end it was not a technical problem, it was a matter of lack of attention.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, can you please enable GPS+Bluetooth and try?

Also if you choose the language BR then your Android device's default language should BR too. If its set to English or other language, it will not work.

Comment: The problem was not in the bluetooth/GPS, as i said previously, nearby was working fine out of google dashboard, and yes the problem was with the "BR", i solved the problem and described how in my own answer 2 days ago, but StackOverflow forced me to wait before accepting it, but thank you btw.